# PHP - Regex to check if <iframe> comes from Google Maps

Tags: php, regex, iframe

I'm trying to validate input from user such as this (yes, the `<iframe>` is the input):

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d7098.94326104394!2d78.0430654485247!3d27.172909818538997!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1385710909804" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

I'm using this regex to check if the input is really an `iframe` AND comes from google map like this (in php):

```
if (!preg_match('/<iframe[^>]*src="https:\/\/w.google.com\/maps\/[^"]+">\s*<\/iframe>/', $input)) {
            return \Response::json(array(
                'type'      => 'danger',
                'message' => 'Embedded map should be in iframe tags!',
            ));
        }
```

This does not work, it never matches all the time (like the input from above). Can someone points me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem appears to be from this part of your regex

```
[^"]+">
```

This is saying anything up until `"` then preceeded by `">`

But in your example it has

```
sen!2s!4v1385710909804" width="600"
```

Which wont match

Also you need to escape the . as this means any character and you missed the three `www` in your regex.

Comment: yeah i only missed the `www`, and what do you mean by escaping the `.`?

Comment: The dot in regex means any character. Its a special character. These need to be escaped to show it is a literal dot. See here for more info: http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

Answer (score 0):

I used this regex:

```
<iframe\s*src="https:\/\/www\.google\.com\/maps\/embed\?[^"]+"*\s*[^>]+>*<\/iframe>
```

And it is working as expected. Hope that helps.

Comment: I need it to work with this src. Can you help me please? 
  -> https://maps.google.com/maps?&q=veracruz&output=embed