# How to validate google map embed code iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps, iframe

I already searched for this topic but unfortunately cannot find the answer.

Is there any way to validate the Google map embed code iframe? Like when user paste the code in a textbox and click a button, system checks if that code is valid. Or is parsing the code and checking for pattern is the only way?

Thank you in advance for any help or idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record I searched for regex that match iframe google embed code.

I found this question: [PHP - Regex to check if <iframe> comes from Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23537960/php-regex-to-check-if-iframe-comes-from-google-maps/39501287#39501287)

And modified the regex:

```
<iframe\s*src="https:\/\/www\.google\.com\/maps\/embed\?[^"]+"*\s*[^>]+>*<\/iframe>
```

Hope that helps someone with same problem. :D Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

Google is giving you the correct code to use. I use it all the time for my friend's real estate websites. Use a responsive iframe code too so it adapts to all the various screen sizes. Use this code, change the iframe source to fit your needs.

```css
/* Flexible iFrame */

.Flexible-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.Flexible-container iframe,
.Flexible-container object,
.Flexible-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Responsive iFrame -->
<div class="flexible-container">
 <!-- Responsive iFrame -->
<div class="flexible-container">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d1457.0935074158538!2d-70.75659948473937!3d43.07956346598421!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xb5e8c11925c54ab4!2sSamonas+Realty+Llc!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1402966179098" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @mlegg Thank you for the reply. Hmm.. I don't think this is what I need. Do you happen to know something to check the code to know if it is valid?

Comment: What do you mean to check if the code is valid? As in it's correct html code?

Comment: Yes. I think the only way is to check for the pattern of the code. Like preg_match. T_T But your answer helped a little so will vote up. :D